# Custom font not loading

Tags: css, fonts

I am looking to use the old "phone book" font for a project I'm working on currently,

I have the fonts and was able to set up a stylesheet for them:

http://interlinked.cf/css/bellgothic.css

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'BellGothicStd';
  src: url('/fonts/bell-gothic/BellGothicStd-Black.otf') format("opentype"),
    url('/fonts/bell-gothic/BellGothicStd-Black.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('/fonts/bell-gothic/BellGothicStd-Black.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'BellGothicStd';
  src: url('/fonts/bell-gothic/BellGothicStd-Bold.otf') format("opentype"),
    url('/fonts/bell-gothic/BellGothicStd-Bold.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('/fonts/bell-gothic/BellGothicStd-Bold.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'BellGothicStd';
  src: url('/fonts/bell-gothic/BellGothicStd-Light.otf') format("opentype"),
    url('/fonts/bell-gothic/BellGothicStd-Light.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('/fonts/bell-gothic/BellGothicStd-Light.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: 100;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'BellGothicBT';
  src: url('/fonts/bell-gothic/BellGothicBT-Black.otf') format("opentype"),
    url('/fonts/bell-gothic/BellGothicStdBT-Black.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('/fonts/bell-gothic/BellGothicStdBT-Black.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'BellGothicBT';
  src: url('/fonts/bell-gothic/BellGothicBT-Bold.otf') format("opentype"),
    url('/fonts/bell-gothic/BellGothicStdBT-Bold.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('/fonts/bell-gothic/BellGothicStdBT-Bold.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

I then tried adding on a page:

```
font-family: BellGothicStd;
```

...which didn't seem to have any effect. I added

```
font-style: normal;
```

and `bold` as well but neither did anything.

If I specify a fallback font, it uses that; otherwise it appears as Times New Roman.

Does anything else need to be done to use my custom font? I have been able to use them in the past with no issue. Perhaps the fonts are corrupted in some way that might prevent using them?

Yes, I am loading the external stylescript in the head, just like the main CSS file. I checked all the syntax and spelling; this happened when testing both locally and on the server.

In the past, I've downloaded complete packages for fonts, and here I just have the fonts themselves; do I need anything else to make it "work"?

**UPDATE**:

Does not work:

```
h1 {
        font-family: 'BellGothicStd';
    }
```

H1 heading now appears as Time News Roman, indicating a failure.

Same thing with:

```
h1 {
    font-family: 'BellGothicStd';
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

The font looks slightly different, but it's still Times New Roman.

Comment: Have you checked in developer tools to see if there is an error loading something?

Comment: What does your complete html markup look like for the text you are trying to load the font to?

Comment: @norcaljohnny Simply .divclass { font-family: BellGothicStd; }

Comment: @InterLinked I meant more like so... h1 {
font-family: 'BellGothicStd', Arial, sans-serif;
font-weight:normal;
font-style:normal;
}

Comment: @InterLinked You need to apply it to text not just a div.

Comment: @InterLinked ie.. h1, h2, h3, p etc

Comment: @InterLinked see my answer I posted

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok here is how it should work.

The CSS

```
@font-face {
font-family: "BellGothicStd";
src: url("fonts/BellGothicStd-Black.otf") format("opentype");
}

h1 {
font-family: 'BellGothicStd', Arial, sans-serif;
font-weight:normal;
font-style:normal;
}
```

The HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
  <title>Font Test</title>

<!-- CSS  -->
  <link href="css/custom.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>

<!-- Main -->
<body>

<h1> This is BellGothicStd font text </h1>

</body>
</html>
```

and the fonts Folder should be located in the CSS folder. Also, remove your forward slashes in the font url.

The result is this 
[Font Test Demo](http://shadtv.onthewifi.com:8080/fonttest/)

Mind you this just one normal font text not light or such.

[image]

And the folder structure

[image: Folder structure]
[image: Folder structure]

Comment: Okay, I moved the fonts directory into the css directory so it matches your directory structure; I am using your exact CSS and HTML, still it does not work (it shows up as Arial)

Comment: Are you using the same otf file as I am? Wondering if that could be the issue...

Comment: I downloaded it online.

Comment: I added this to my head and still no change: <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://shadtv.onthewifi.com:8080/fonttest/css/custom.css"> - so even using your stylesheet isn't fixing it, bizarre...

Comment: @InterLinked You may have a bad font file. Try downloading it from a different source.

Comment: That would explain it, what source did you use?

Comment: @InterLinked https://www.dafontfree.net/freefonts-bell-gothic-std-f64554.htm

Comment: Unfortunately, that is the same source I used so that seems to rule that out. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

**This is probably due to CORS** and is expected behaviour. I know it sounds confusing, but the reason is due to the source of your fonts and not the web page itself.

An explanation I wrote for a similar issue with different solutions for Apache, NGINX, IIS or PHP available in multiple languages can be found here:

https://www.hirehop.com/blog/cross-domain-fonts-cors-font-face-issue/